# How do I display only a subset of a datasource in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

I want to swap out the content of a tableview.  The data source has elements with a flag that denotes whether or not they should be shown.

Ultimately, I want to be able to swap what is shown, depending on the flags.  For now, though, I'll settle on an answer to the following.

**How can my table display only a subset of the datasource?**

I am *not* asking for a [tableView reload], which seems to be what most of my searches yielded.  I want to show only some of the datasource items at a time based on a criteria (the flag, in this case).

As an example for clarity, here's a sample of the functionality.

---

We have 50 Friend elements in an array.  It is the datasource for our table.  When we load the app, all 50 friends are shown.

20 of those friends are marked as "Awesome" within the Friend class.  When you tap the Awesome button, those 20 are shown in the table.

10 of them are marked as "Lame" within the Friend class.  When you tap the Lame button, those 10 are shown in the table.

---

What methods do I need to look at to achieve that?  TableView discussions are huge and I've been looking through bugs and errors without satisfying results, so far.

Comment: In short, that is not directly possible. Use a combination of the given answers to get it done.

Comment: The answers below address your issue, but the key is that you misunderstand what a "datasource" means. The tableview displays exactly what the datasource provides. It is up to the datasource to filter, sort, merge, transform, or otherwise manipulate the data into the form the table needs. You're confusing the datasource with the model. The model should be separate from the datasource, and the datasource filters, sorts, etc. things it retrieves from the model.

Comment: Thanks a ton, @RobNapier. That makes sense; I never knew that the MVC threshold was drawn so across the datasource.

Comment: The datasource has a role similar to the ViewModel in the MVVM architectural pattern that Microsoft uses. There are a few proponents of Cocoa developers studying MVVM; it may match what we do in practice closer than MVC does (I haven't come to a decision on MVVM; the MVCS architecture that Big Nerd Ranch advocates is probably closer to what I generally do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep two data structures. The first is the master set of data. The second contains just the data you want to display. Point the table to the second set of data.

Basically, when you want to reload the table with a different subset, create a new array, iterate the master data set and add just the objects you want to the new array.

SInce the second array just have references to the original objects from the master array, there is little extra overhead for this.

**Update**: To expand on the comment by Rob Napier, the master data structure I mentioned would be the "model" and the second data structure would be the data that backs the table's data source.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense and I think I know how to implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up an `NSPredicate` to filter the values that will be returned by the fetchResults:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResults {
...

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"flag == %@", @"Awesome"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];  

...
```

This will only return those records that meet the criteria of the `NSPredicate`.

Comment: Isn't this specific to Core Data? There's no indication that Core Data is being used.

Comment: True, but the principal of an NSPredicate can apply to any datasource, not just Core Data.

Comment: This is going to be useful for the filtering of the data, so thanks!  I've upvoted your answer.  The other one speaks to actually displaying that filtered data in the table, so it's the one I'm marking as the answer.